# <audio> stops when I'm using alert() js

Tags: javascript, html

I have got an issue using alert() in JavaScript. When message appears,  tag stops playing .mp3 file. Is it JavaScript bug or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: yea that's because the alert box stops code execution, show your code to find out what you need an alert for

Comment: <audio loop autoplay>
        <source src="music.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>

Comment: <audio loop autoplay>
        <source src="music.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>

Answer (score 0):

`alert` has nothing to do with your audio stopping. The audio are not running on the same JS thread with your code. Take a look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/p0tp7v9z/) and [the HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content.html#the-audio-element):

> When an audio element is **potentially playing**, it must have its audio data played synchronised with the current playback position, at the element's effective media volume.

By saying "[potentially playing](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content.html#potentially-playing)", it means the following:

> A media element is said to be **potentially playing** when its paused attribute is false, the element has not ended playback, playback has not stopped due to errors, the element either has no current media controller or has a current media controller but is not blocked on its media controller, and the element is not a blocked media element.

`alert` doesn't fit into anywhere in the specification so it should not affect your audio.

So your audio might be stopped by many reasons. It might be that your audio file is broken, or perhaps some of your code isn't functioning as you expected (did you check to see if there is any `.pause()` method calling from your code?). Without seeing any of your code it is hard to diagnose the problem, but it is sure that `alert` isn't the one causing the issue.